# Fetching jqgrid row on click of hyperlink

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing problem in Jqgrid. I have a column with hyperlink and on the click of that hyperlink I want row data. Is this possible using Jqgrid. when I am using "getGridParam" I am getting row id as null.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities you can try here:

1) You can use a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter) to create the hyperlink, and have a custom attribute on the link where you put in the rowid (prefix the custom attribute name with 'data-' to keep it html5 compatible). Alternatively you could call a javascript function explicitly passing the row id.

2) Instead of the hyperlink's event itself, try using the [onCellSelect event of jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) where you get the row and column id of the clicked cell, even if its a hyperlink. But this would trigger the event even if the user clicks anywhere inside the cell, not just on the link!.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Can you suggest with code sample.

Comment: sure I'll try to extract a generalized implementation by tomorrow.

Comment: PS: Can you put in the code on how you're generating the hyperlink? Are you using a custom formatter or any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you found the answer to this by now but for some of you using ASP.NET WebForm here is what I used.

Create the Custom Formatter and add it to the column where you want the link to appear:
My columns are from a database I use a Select statement as so:

```
switch (jqGrdCol.DataField)
{
  case "xxx":
     CustomFormatter hypLinkxxx = new CustomFormatter();
     hypLinkxxx.FormatFunction = "xxxformatOperations"; --> **JavaScript Function**
     jqGrdCol.Formatter.Add(hypLinkxxx);
  break;
}
```

Then in the Javascript function:

```
function xxxformatOperations(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href=somefile.aspx?xxx=" + rowObject[0] >" + cellvalue + "</font></a>"
}
```

I get the value of the column as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was did look into your question to figure out a solution and I have found out a solution to this.

The solution is by using `onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event)`

this gives the rowid and contents ie the content of the cell you have clicked or selected 
therfore you can get the entire row of contents which includes your hyperlink as well